# In awk, when is a function definition executed?

Tags: awk

In awk, when is a function definition executed?

Is a function definition executed even before `BEGIN {...}` is executed? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This is easily determined; I got curious and decided to test the "worst-case" scenario first, by defining the function at the end of the awk scriptfile:

```
$ cat go.awk
BEGIN {
  print "The BEGIN block is executing"
  print reverse("The BEGIN block is executing")
}

{
  print reverse($0)
}

function reverse(str) {
  trs=""
  for(i=length(str); i > 0; i--) {
    trs=trs substr(str, i, 1);
  }
  return trs
}
```

And with:

```
$ cat input
line one
line two
line three
```

... the result is:

```
$ awk -f go.awk < input
The BEGIN block is executing
gnitucexe si kcolb NIGEB ehT
eno enil
owt enil
eerht enil
```

You can see that the function was defined (the function "definition" was "executed") before the BEGIN block was entered, since the BEGIN block successfully called my user-defined `reverse` function.

To see that the function is not *executed* while it's being defined, simply insert a `print` statement inside the function and observe that there is no output from that statement until the function is *called*.

The [POSIX specification for awk](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) says, most pertinently:

> A function can be referred to anywhere in an awk program; in particular, its use can precede its definition. The scope of a function is global.

The [gawk man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/awk) implies something similar:

> ... Gawk reads the program text as if all the program-files and command line source texts had been concatenated together.   This  is  useful  for
>       building  libraries  of  AWK functions, without having to include them in each
>       new AWK program that uses them.  It also provides the ability to  mix  library
>       functions with command line programs.
>
> ...
>
> Gawk  executes  AWK  programs  in  the  following  order.  First, all variable
>       assignments specified via the -v option are performed.   Next,  gawk  compiles
>       the  program into an internal form.  Then, gawk executes the code in the BEGIN
>       rule(s) (if any), and then proceeds ...

Comment: This is a good example of how people can experiment and learn answers for themselves.  Well done.